# Priority queue adding new object vs adding already created

Tags: java, mapreduce, priority-queue

Im writing a mapreduce program where in reduce function receives as input value an iterable of PageRankNode(with two fields) object and im adding it to priority queue. On iterating over each object and adding it to priority queue, the resultant priority queue only contains the last object i added. 
However, it seems to work as expected when i create a new object of the same type and add to priority queue.

I was wondering why is this happening?
Below sample works. However instead of "topPages.add(new PageRankNode(pageNode.pageName,pageNode.pageRank))", i use "topPages.add(pageNode)" it doesnt work as expected.

The comparator implementation for the priority queue is also added below.

```
private Comparator<PageRankNode> comparator= new PageNodeComparator();
    private PriorityQueue<PageRankNode> topPages= new PriorityQueue<PageRankNode>(100,comparator);

public void reduce(NullWritable key,Iterable<PageRankNode> pageNodes,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
    for(PageRankNode pageNode:pageNodes){
        //topPages.add(pageNode);
        topPages.add(new PageRankNode(pageNode.pageName,pageNode.pageRank));
        if(topPages.size()>100){
            topPages.poll();
        }
    }
    PageRankNode pageNode;
    while(!topPages.isEmpty()){
        pageNode=topPages.poll();
        context.write(NullWritable.get(),new Text(pageNode.pageName+":"+pageNode.pageRank));
    }

}
public class PageNodeComparator implements Comparator<PageRankNode>{

    public int compare(PageRankNode x,PageRankNode y){
        if(x.pageRank < y.pageRank){
            return -1;
        }
        if(x.pageRank > y.pageRank){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you provided enough information to properly diagnose this.  I see that you have `InterruptedException` in the `reduce` method suggesting that you might be running this on multiple threads -- if so that might be the underlying cause.

I wrote a small program that does the same and its output is as expected.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Main {
  private static Comparator<PageRankNode> comparator = new PageNodeComparator();
  private static PriorityQueue<PageRankNode> topPages = new PriorityQueue<PageRankNode>(100, comparator);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    reduce(Arrays.asList(
      new PageRankNode("A", 1000),
      new PageRankNode("B", 1500),
      new PageRankNode("C", 500),
      new PageRankNode("D", 700),
      new PageRankNode("E", 7000),
      new PageRankNode("F", 60)
    ));
  }

  public static void reduce(Iterable<PageRankNode> pageNodes) {
    for(PageRankNode pageNode : pageNodes) {
      //topPages.add(pageNode);
      topPages.add(new PageRankNode(pageNode.pageName, pageNode.pageRank));
      if(topPages.size() > 100) {
        topPages.poll();
      }
    }
    PageRankNode pageNode;
    while(!topPages.isEmpty()) {
      pageNode = topPages.poll();
      System.out.println(pageNode.pageName);
    }
  }

  public static class PageRankNode {
    private String pageName;
    private int pageRank;

    public PageRankNode(String pageName, int pageRank) {
      this.pageName = pageName;
      this.pageRank = pageRank;
    }
  }

  public static class PageNodeComparator implements Comparator<PageRankNode> {

    @Override
    public int compare(PageRankNode x, PageRankNode y) {
      if(x.pageRank < y.pageRank) {
        return -1;
      }
      if(x.pageRank > y.pageRank) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
F
C
D
A
B
E
```